# Migrar aplicación php+jquery+Ajax hacia Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ajax, bootstrap

hace un tiempo hice una implementación en php de un pequeño sistema de gestión de pedidos que funciona actualmente. Básicamente utilicé html, php, jquery, bootstrap y ajax.

En términos generales, hay un formulario inicial con varios tabs de información. En cada tab, se ingresa diferente tipo de información, a través de cuadros de textos, selección en listas desplegables, nombre de archivos que se deben subir como documentos adjuntos.

```
 <form name="frm_nsol"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frm_subedoc">
                            <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                                <!--TAB FONDOS-->
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando se le da clic al botón Enviar Solicitud, se valida los datos del formulario y una vez que se ha validado todo y está ok, creo un objeto FormData donde meto el formulario y luego lo paso a una llamada Ajax, que invoca un archivo php que realiza el pre-procesamiento para la inserción en la BD.

```
                    var Form=new FormData($("#frm_subedoc")[0]);
                $("#mostrarmodalregistrandosolicitud").modal("show");
                $.ajax({
                    url:"procesar.php",
                    type:"post",
                    data:Form,
                    processData:false,
                    contentType:false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(respuesta1)
                    {
                        $("#mostrarmodalregistrandosolicitud").modal("hide");
                        //alert(respuesta1)
                        //console.log(respuesta1);
                        $("#archivos").val('');
                        $("#mostrarmodalresumen").modal("show");
                        $("#cabeceramodalresumen").append('<h3>Resumen de la Solicitud De Compra Generada</h3>');
                        $("#cuerpomodalresumen").append('<p align="center"><b>NÚMERO DE SOLICITUD:</b> '+respuesta1+'<br><hr>');
```

Este archivo "procesar.php" invocado por Ajax, realiza las siguientes acciones:

1. Extrae todos los datos pasados en el objeto FormData.
2. Realiza todas las inserciones o actualizaciones en BD, entre ellas, una inserción del tipo maestro detalle.
3. Codifica los nombres de los archivos que se van a subir y los sube a una ruta en el servidor de la aplicación.
4. Envía un correo a una lista de destinatarios con el aviso de la solicitud generada.

Extracto #1:

```
$antecedente=$_POST["antecedente"];          
$materia=$_POST["materia"];        
$solicitud=$_POST["solicitud"];    
$tipocompra0=$_POST["tipocompra"];    
$tipofondo=$_POST["tipofondo"];
```

Extracto #2:

```
$sql1="insert into solicitud(idoc, antecedente, materia, descsolicitud, idtipocompra, desacquisicion, area, dimension,practicas,resutados,totalsol,fecha,idestado,idunidad,iddirector,idusuario)
values('$idoc','$antecedente','$materia','$solicitud', '$tipocompra','$descadquisicion', '$area', '$dimension', '$practicas', '$resultados', '$totalsol', '$fec', '$idestado','$idunidad','$iddirector','$idusuario')";

$q1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1) or die("Error Error al grabar la solicitud");
$idsolicitud=mysqli_insert_id($con);  
//VALOR AUTOINCREMENTO DEL ULTIMO REGISTRO INSERTADO                                       
//SIRVE PARA CREAR LAS RELACIONES CON LAS OTRAS TABLAS

//GRABAMOS LOS TIPOS DE FONDOS SELECCIONADOS  
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($tipofondo);$i++){
    $sqlfondos="INSERT INTO cargaen(idsolicitud, idtipofondo) 
            VALUES ('$idsolicitud', '$tipofondo[$i]')";
    $qfondos=mysqli_query($con,$sqlfondos) or die("Problemas al insertar Tipos de Fondos"); 
};
```

Extracto #3:

```
foreach($files as $fileID=>$file)
{
    $secuencia++;
    $fileContent=file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
    $nuevonombre=$_SESSION['usuario']."_".$secuencia."_".microtime()."_".$file['name'];
    $nombreoriginal=$file['name'];
    file_put_contents($carpeta."/".$nuevonombre,$fileContent);
    //GRABAMOS LOS DOCUMENTOS ADJUNTADOS
    $sqladjuntado="INSERT INTO adjuntado(idsolicitud,secuencia,nombreoriginal,nombrealmacenado) 
    VALUES('$idsolicitud','$secuencia','$nombreoriginal','$nuevonombre')";
    $qadjuntado=mysqli_query($con,$sqladjuntado) or die("Problemas al insertar Nombre de documentos adjuntados");                  
};
```

Extracto #4:

```
$destino = trim($destino, ',');
$asunto="";
$asunto=$_SESSION['unidad']." ha generado la solicitud de compra Nro:".$idsolicitud;
$cuerpo="";
$cuerpo=$cuerpo."MATERIA: ".$materia;
mail($destino,$asunto,$cuerpo);
```

Una vez recibida la respuesta OK de la llamada Ajax, se levanta un modal con la información resumen de la solicitud y al dar clic al botón Cerrar el Resumen, se genera un formulario pdf con la información de la solicitud.

```
            $("#cerrarresumen").click(function()
            {
                $("#frm_subedoc")[0].reset();
                $('#pills-tab a[href="#fondos"]').tab('show');
                $('#fondos').tab('show');
                $("#idoc").focus();
                window.open("tcpdf/examples/generadocspdf.php", "Generación de Documentos","location=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,width=1400,height=700");
            });
```

Ahora estoy comenzando a pasar este proyecto a Laravel, por que leí en la documentación que me ofrece mejores aspectos de seguridad, control de accesos y otras cosas del trabajo con la BD.

Todo el front (php+jquery) lo he pasado y resuelto algunos problemas pequeños, está funcionando bien el despliegue.

Ahora estoy con el tema más asociado al backend y es ahí en donde me surje las siguiente dudas:

Puedo seguir utilizando Ajax,  para pasar los datos al preprocesamiento en el otro archivo, tal como lo hago ahora o tiene alguna variación en el llamado al archivo php o en laravel se hace de otra forma?

Puedo seguir utilizando el objeto FormData para llevar todos los datos del formulario y pasarlo al Ajax, tal como lo hago ahora?

Puedo seguir subiendo los archivos de la misma forma como lo hago ahora o Laravel tiene formas más eficientes?

Puedo seguir enviando los correos así como lo tengo en PHP?

Yo entiendo que sí, pues entiendo que Laravel es un framework php, pero tengo la impresión de que en Laravel pueden estar resueltas estas cosas de otra forma más eficiente o más seguras.

Si requieren más información, por favor me avisan para agregarlo.

Agradezco todo aporte.

Comment: ¿Ya revisaste la documentación sobre [emails](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail)?, lo de usar Ajax claro que si lo puedes usar pero tendrá algunas variaciones en función de que NO mandas llamar al archivo propiamente sino a la ruta por ejemplo, lo de formData es tema de JS así  que no tiene nada que ver con Laravel, tu pregunta por otro lado es demasiado amplia y contiene múltiples dudas, te recomiendo tratar algo y en función de los posibles errores modificar tu pregunta

Comment: Busca aqui en la comunidad, ya existen muchas publicaciones sobre Ajax y Laravel

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @BetaM y comprendo lo que me dices en el sentido de que no estoy planteando ningún problema o error específico, producto de alguna implementación. Más bien, la idea era tener una opinión en base a la información que puse en la pregunta y la experiencia de esta comunidad para que alguien me pudiera decir algo así como lo que tu me has dicho en tu respuesta, que Ajax sí se puede usar con alguna variación, que revise emails para el tema de correo, tal vez lo único que no me dices es sobre la implementación del pdf. Tomo tu consejo y buscaré en la comunidad. Gracias